# App looks different in Main.storyboard than in simulator

Tags: ios

I am learning to program in XCode 7 and Swift 2. I built my app in Main.storyboard, but when I run it in the simulator it looks completely different.

Here are the photos so you can see what I am talking about.

Main.storyboard: http://shrani.si/f/3y/12M/34bm1y0G/1.jpg

Simulator: http://shrani.si/f/1t/ZZ/2AklkVvt/2.jpg

What do I need to do to make it appear the same as in the Main.storyboard?

Thank you for any help,
Aleks

Comment: You need to add constraints :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set Constraints.

The easiest way to do it is clicking the triangle and then "Add Missing Constraints" or "Reset to Suggested Constraints" (All Views in XYZ)

[image: Example]

It takes a bunch of time to really understand how constraints and auto layout is working. And Xcode helped me a lot with the suggested constraints...

Here is a good tutorial for the start:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: the constraints already make it look as expected in the simulator, but the storyboard displays it wrongly.